# management of big number of parameters of a keyword in VBscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, automation, automated-tests, hp-uft

I'm working on test automation using keyword driven framework. I have to add a keyword add_car. This keyword needs a big number of parameters that should be entered in the excel sheet as parameters for this keyword.

I want to find a solution to manage the big number of parameters(some of them are always required and the others are optional)

The below picture is an example of how the values of parameters are entered in the Excel sheet.

[excel sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg1Fu.png)

Here is how I call this keyword in UFT

[keyword Call in UFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b24i.png)

And in my Functions Library, I defined the instructions of my_keyword.

Is there any solution to manage this big number of parameters(I have more than 30 parameter in general some are optional and others are always required).

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise walking through your worksheet to get all parameters and store them into a dictionary. Then you would call your functions by calling the dictionary instead of all parameters individually.

The way to manage all of the parameters to add them into dictionary would have to be handled in a separate function and you could then check if the parameters exist/have values inside your functions or even externally. It would actually be kind of a whole new framework just to work with it, but when you're done, you could reuse the functions anywhere you wanted.

At least that was the way implemented in the project I've worked (though I was not the one to implement it).
It is hard to provide a thorough answer about the topic because it is pretty extensive, but for starters, I'd recommend this link about working with dictionaries:

http://automated-360.com/qtpuft/advanced-concepts/everything-dictionary-object/

In a very brief way, `Dictionary` objects are sort of a collection of `Key`,`Item` pairs, where you could store your parameters like `Parameter1`,`ParameterValue` to use later.
It also allows you to sort your parameters, check for existence, store them in a Case Insensitive way, edit them, delete them and so forth.

This is what I can offer to you now.
Happy research and happy coding.

Comment: Thank you for your help Victor but how can I deal with the link between my excel sheet and my dictionary. If I have to use a keyword to store my parameters into the dictionary I will be in the same situationa keyword with a big number of parameters. If you have an idea about how to store my parameters into the dictionary without calling a keyword please help me. Thank you again for your help

Comment: The way we implemented (in a very broad explanation) is to create a main function that would read the excel in a loop per row. Inside that loop we would then have another loop per column to get all of the parameters (filled or not) and store it into a global dictionary. Once we have all of the parameters we would call the keyword function using `eval(keyword)` where keyword is the function name, provided in the spreadsheet in the same way you are doing. `eval ` returns true or false so your functions should also return that in order to determine if test passed or failed. Does this help?

Comment: Again, we created a framework for that, that can be used on any project because the concept would always be the same (get all user info from the spreadsheet and work with it). And about having a lot of parameters, you can't escape that, but by using dictionaries, your functions wouldn't have to receive the parameters in the function declaration. Just create all of them as `Function myFunction()` if you are using public dictionary or as `Function myFunction(myDictionary)` if you are passing the dictionary as parameter. Then you would work with the parameters you need from inside the function

Comment: One other thing (and this is already too extensive): we were working with named parameters instead of just `Parameter1`. It is easier to work with a parameter like `Username` rather than just a generic parameter, but you could also make it work

Comment: Yeees This is very helpful, and I just define the dictionary as a unique parameter for my function (keyword) is it ? I think in this case the hardest task is to creat e the main function that would read the excel in a loop per row, to get all the parameters to match each entered value in the spreadsheet  values with the correspendant parameter in the dictionary, is it ?

Comment: yeah for me now I have to focus more on how to match parameterX of the rowY with its correspondent in the dictionary because we are using parameterX instead of naming directly the parameters in our case.

Comment: on other question please because this will be my first use of dictionaries, if I want to add a parameter can I only add it manually to the dictionary ?

Comment: That's correct. The dictionary would contain all your parameters in a `key, value` pair. Since you would work with this in s loop, for every row you would have to reset the dictionary. This way you would only have the parameters for the current row in it. I'd still advise you to work with named parameters though. Instead of having a single line for each keyword, work with two. Where you have `value of param1` would actually be the name of the parameters required for that specific function. Then in the row below you would have the values. You would still have the generic first row for reference

Comment: To add parameters to dictionary is easy: `Set dictParam = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")` to have the dictionary object and then `dictParam.Add "ParamKey", "ParamValue"`. This is explained in detail from the link in my answer ;)

Comment: yeah, I'm thinking too about having two rows for each keyword but this may affect testing my old scripts because in UFT I will call a function that stores all the parameters by name and in my old scripts I'm not working with the same approach. It hard to take the right  dicision in my case ...

Comment: Depending on the amount of old test cases you have, it would be a good idea to make the decision now and maybe refactor the old test cases for the new approach, but that would be up to you. Unfortunately I think we've already extended this topic too much. Try to work with the info you have and, if you find further issues, post a new question. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how many parameters do you have. 
However, I have 600+ parameters required for 1 test case (I know... It's a huge end to end test that takes loads of parameters).
I have used different tabs in excel sheet to logically separate the test data parameters.

I read the excel as database (using ADODB.connection) and query each tab in excel to get the row that I need. I can write SQL join to query from multiple excel tabs at once.

Reference on reading excel as DB:
http://www.automation.ultimatetimepass.com/index.php/home/qtp/excel/qtp-read-excel-using-adodb-connection/10-qtp-excel

Answer (score 0):

Few thoughts on this.

Possible solution 1: Text File Approach

You will have all the parameters are stored with key,value combination like given below in the text file.

```
Parameter1=abc
Parameter2=def
Parameter3=ghi
```

The advantage here is when any of your parameter not needed, just remove from the text file.That being said, Your framework engine should read the keyword "ReadFile" as function and return a collection of string from file.

sParameterList = ReadFile("")

Possible solution 2:

Define all the parameters with comma separated value.Split and pass it your function call.

```
Parameter1=abc,Parameter2=def,Parameter3=ghi
```

[image: Implementation]

Comment: Thank you for your help. We are actually working with textFile in some parts of our project and my task is to automate this means no use of TextFile and If I will use the second approach maybe I have to modify the old scripts to put all the paerameters in one cell in order of multiple cells.